# Control text in EditText into AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I try to check the insert text from user into AlertDialog with this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(
                getString(R.string.search_button),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {


                        mNome = editext.getText().toString();
                        mCognome = editext1.getText().toString();

                        View focusView = null;



                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mNome) && TextUtils.isEmpty(mCognome)) {
                            editext.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                            focusView = editext;
                            cancel=true;
                            focusView.requestFocus();

                        }
                        else{
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        go();}

                    }
                });

        mAlertDialog = builder.create();
        mAlertDialog.show();
```

But not work, the if the text is empty the AlertDialog disappears

Comment: what do you want the behaviour when the text is empty?

Comment: i want to to focus to EditText into AlertDialog, to insert text

Comment: what i can see is a variable focusView is null and you are trying focusView.requestFocus(). Plz check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
                 edittext.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: inside the Fragment how i can use getSystemService ?

Comment: yes always, if the text is empty or not when i click on the PositiveButton on the AlertDialog, the AlertDialog disappears

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so check your `String` like this :

`if(Your_String == null)` **or** `if(Your_String.isEmpty())`

Hope it will work.

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi .. check by 2nd condition

Comment: The problem is, the control work and the app enter in the ''IF'' control and not in the ''ELSE'' but AlertDialog always disappears

Comment: maybe the problem is because the AlertDialog is in the Fragment?